# Why does this memoizer work on recursive functions?

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I can't figure out why the following code is makes `fib` run in linear rather than exponential time.

```
def memoize(obj):
    """Memoization decorator from PythonDecoratorLibrary. Ignores
    **kwargs"""

    cache = obj.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return memoizer

@memoize
def fib(n):
    return n if n in (0, 1) else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

For example, `fib(100)` doesn't completely blow up like I expected it to.

My understanding is that `@memoize` sets `fib = memoize(fib)`. So when you call `fib(100)`, seeing that `100` is not in the cache, it will call `obj` on `100`. But `obj` is the *original `fib` function*, so shouldn't it take just as long (on the first evaluation) as if we didn't have memoization at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names are resolved *lexically*.  Just because you call a function named `fib` from within a function named `fib`, that doesn't mean it would necessarilly be the same `fib`.

A (highly inaccurate) demonstration of what's going on is this:

```
def fib(n):
    return n if n in (0, 1) else globals()['fib'](n-1) + globals()['fib'](n-2)
```

Since the decorater affects `globals`, you get the decorated `fib` at the time the recursive call occurs.

Answer (score 6):

`obj` in the decorator is indeed the wrapped, unmodified, non-memoized function. However, when said function tries to recurse, it looks up the global name `fib`, get the memoized wrapper function, and hence also causes the 99th, 98th, ... fibonacci number to be memoized along the way.

Answer (score 2):

"But obj is the original fib function, so shouldn't it take just as long (on the first evaluation) as if we didn't have memoization at all?"

`obj` (in `memoizer`) is the indeed original `fib` function.  The trick is that when `fib` calls itself recursively, it's calling `memoize(fib)`.

```
def fib(n):
    return n if n in (0, 1) else wrapped(fib(n-1)) + wrapped(fib(n-2))
```

Where `wrapped` is the function generated by functools that calls memoize.memoizer.  Kinda.

The recursive calls might end up being simple lookups in `obj.cache` (theoretically O(1)) which is what improves the perf significantly.