# Memoization python function

Tags: python, function, memoization

Here's a little piece of code which converts every function to its memoization version.

```
def memoize(f): # Memoize a given function f
    def memf(*x):
        if x not in memf.cache:
            memf.cache[x] = f(*x)
        return memf.cache[x]

    memf.cache = {}
    return memf
```

For instance, if we have a function `fib` as follows which returns the `n`th Fibonacci number:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Now, the above function can be memoized by using

```
fib = memoize(fib)
```

Everything is fine up to this point but what I can't understand is that if we do something like this, instead of:

```
fib = memoize(fib)
```

we instead do:

```
fib2 = memoize(fib)
```

the function `fib2` isn't a `memoize`d function of `fib`. When we run `fib2` it runs like ordinary fib. Please explain why this `memoize` function gets applied to say a function `f` if and only if we use:

```
f = memoize(f)
```

The memoization code is taken from 6.00x a MOOC provided by edx.org. It's not running right now that's why I have come here to ask.

Comment: This question is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909200/why-does-this-memoizer-work-on-recursive-functions?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when `fib2` recursively calls

```
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

that is the original, un-`memoize`d version; you only get the benefit of the decorator on the first call to `fib2`, not all the recursive calls to vanilla `fib`.

Here's what happens:

1. When you call `fib2`, you are really calling `memf`, which
2. calls `fib` in turn if the arguments aren't in the cache (as they won't be on the first call), then
3. `fib`, being recursive *calls `fib`*. This is **not** the decorated version `fib2`, so all of the rest of the recursive calls aren't being `memoize`d.

If you call `fib2` again with the same arguments, that *will* be returned from the cache, but you have lost most of the benefit.

You can create decorated functions *in general* using:

```
decorated = decorator(original)
```

but as your function being decorated is *recursive*, you run into problems.

---

Below is a demo example. Create two identical `fib` functions, `fib_dec` and `fib_undec`. Modify the decorator to tell you what it's doing:

```
def memoize(f): # Memoize a given function f
    def memf(*x):
        print("Memoized call.")
        if x not in memf.cache:
            print("Filling cache.")
            memf.cache[x] = f(*x)
        else:
            print("Cache retrieve.")
        return memf.cache[x]
    memf.cache = {}
    return memf
```

Then run:

```
fib_dec = memoize(fib_dec) # fully memoized
fib_undec_1 = memoize(fib_undec) # not fully memoized

print("Calling fib_dec(2)")
print(fib_dec(2))
print("Calling fib_dec(1)")
print(fib_dec(1))
print("Calling fib_undec_1(2)")
print(fib_undec_1(2))
print("Calling fib_undec_1(1)")
print(fib_undec_1(1))
print("Calling fib_undec_1(2)")
print(fib_undec_1(2))
```

This will give:

```
Calling fib_dec(2) # fully decorated
Memoized call.
Filling cache.
Memoized call.
Filling cache.
Memoized call. # recusive calls all memoized
Filling cache.
2
Calling fib_dec(1)
Memoized call.
Cache retrieve. # previous recursive result cached
1
Calling fib_undec_1(2) # not fully memoized
Memoized call. # only one memoized call, recursion not memoized
Filling cache.
2
Calling fib_undec_1(1)
Memoized call.
Filling cache. # recursive result not cached
1
Calling fib_undec_1(2)
Memoized call.
Cache retrieve. # but original call is cached
2
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate. I couldn't make much sense of it right now.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating but its still unclear to me. Suppose we use the correct thing that is fib = memoize(fib) then fib will call fib which will next call fib. In this way they will never make it to the definition that fib = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) so how will I get my answer?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that fib will call memoize(fib) but since fib inside of memoize is indeed fib that's why memoize(fib) will call memoize(fib)(n-1) and memoize(fib)(n-2). This will go on forever and fib definition that when n<= 1 return 1 will never be reached.

Comment: Yes it will - at some point you will call `memoize(fib)(1)`. The first time that happens, `memf` will call `fib(1)` and `cache` the result (effectively `cache.update({1: 1})`) after that it will be retrieved from the `cache` like any other value.

Comment: Please explain how the thing works when we use fib = memoize(fib).

Comment: OMG! Now I get it. Thanks a lot jonrsharpe.

Comment: No problem - I have added an example comparison at the end of the answer that will hopefully demonstrate exactly what is going on.